# Xamarin.iOS Error: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _object_equals_object

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, realm

I am using realm.net with my Tamarin project. When I try to debug my application with device it showing 116 errors. Even error message starts with  `Native linking failed, undefined symbol:` I tried lots of combinations like clean/rebuild, removed Realm package and added again. Restarted Xamarin studio and mac etc. But still getting error.

Full error message is:(only Two added)

```
/Users<path/to/project>/MTOUCH: Error MT5214: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _object_equals_object. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Realms.ObjectHandle/NativeMethods.equals_object. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked. (MT5214) (Project.iOS)

/Users<path/to/project>/MTOUCH: Error MT5214: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _object_get_nullable_int64. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Realms.ObjectHandle/NativeMethods.get_nullable_int64. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked. (MT5214) (Project.iOS)
```

How to remove this errors

**UPDATE:**
My XS info

```
=== Xamarin Studio Community ===

Version 6.1.2 (build 44)
Installation UUID: 78fd21d5-9603-4a13-a6bf-e7e25e1a7fc3
Runtime:
    Mono 4.8.0 (mono-4.8.0-branch/f5fbc32) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

    Package version: 408000344

=== NuGet ===

Version: 3.4.3.0

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Not Installed

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 7.3 (10183.3)
Build 7D175

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 10.4.0.20 (Xamarin Studio Community)
Hash: 62816dd
Branch: master
Build date: 2016-11-15 06:24:02-0500

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 3.0.0.290 (Xamarin Studio Community)

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 7.1.0.2 (Xamarin Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/johnykutty/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        6.0 (API level 23)

SDK Tools Version: 25.1.2
SDK Platform Tools Version: 24.0.0
SDK Build Tools Version: 23.0.2

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Xamarin Android Player ===

Not Installed

=== Xamarin Inspector ===

Version: 1.0.0.0
Hash: 1f3067d
Branch: master
Build date: 11/16/2016 2:43:59 AM

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 601020044
Git revision: 0ccfcd52b95305ebd5b7eca0d88c1017035910ae
Build date: 2016-10-28 15:12:43-04
Xamarin addins: a39a869d8a78d87bdc6775f696c13a4cc9024501
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-cycle8

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.11.6
Darwin <System name> 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0
    Mon Aug 29 20:21:34 PDT 2016
    root:xnu-3248.60.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

=== Enabled user installed addins ===

Xamarin Inspector 1.0.0.0
```

Also using Realm.net 0.80.0

Comment: Can you add some more information such as your Xamarin Studio and Xamarin.iOS versions? Also, would it be possible to add the complete build log in a gist or pastebin?

Comment: @Tayschrenn added the IDE information.

Comment: Do you use any other NuGet libraries? Also, what happens if you use latest Xamarin.iOS from the Stable channel?

Comment: After updating Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin studio, its working fine now